# Discord.js: GuildMember's setMute command not working?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm currently attempting to program the mute functionality onto a discord bot. It has the server permission "mute members" enabled.

This is the code that is getting run whenever I call the mute command:

```
if(!receiverG.mute) { 
                            message.channel.send(`${receiver} muted by ${sender}.`)
                            receiverG.setMute(true, remaining); 
                        } 
else {
                            message.channel.send(`${receiver} unmuted by ${sender}.`)
                            receiverG.setMute(false, remaining); 
}
message.channel.send(receiverG.mute);
```

So, consecutive calls of this code should toggle mute, but message.channel.send.(receiverG.mute) sends "false" everytime, indicating that the member never got muted. I'm unclear how the mute functionality works with discord. I read somewhere that it's based on roles- if so, then what would be the point of a setMute() command?

Documentation: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setMute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setMute()` returns a promise. Therefore, you must wait for it to be completed before sending the status of the member.

```js
await receiverG.setMute(true, remaining);
```

Remember that `await` can only be used in async functions. Make sure to also catch and handle an error if the promise were to be rejected (`.catch()` or `try...catch`).

As for the functionality of `setMute()`, it should be equivalent to right clicking on a member in a voice channel and selecting `Server Mute`.